# Cannot Open Multiple Profiles At Once in DrissionPage

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've been using undetected chromedriver for a while but switched to DrissionPage recently.

One thing that I can't seem to do is to open multiple chrome profiles at once while using DrissionPage.

Is there a solution to this?

On undetected chromedriver I could open multiple chrome profiles at once so I used similar logic on DrissionPage and read the docs but can't seem to get it working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://g1879.gitee.io/drissionpagedocs/ChromiumPage/create_page_object/#_8

It says so in DrissionPage's documentation, see this.